# rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 18 column 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is the full error I am getting when doing a simple:

`$ rails generate`

> Users/localuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in
>   `parse':  (): could not find expected ':' while scanning a
>   simple key at line 18 column  3(Psych::SyntaxError)

Any ideas whats going on?

My system:

- ruby 2.0.0p0 [x86_64-darwin12.2.0] Rails 3.2.13 mysql Ver 14.14
  Distrib 5.6.10, for osx10.8 (x86_64)

This an extract of the psych.rb file mentioned in the error

```
#See Psych::Nodes for more information about YAML AST.
def self.parse_stream yaml, filename = nil, &block
  if block_given?
    parser = Psych::Parser.new(Handlers::DocumentStream.new(&block))
    parser.parse yaml, filename
  else
    parser = self.parser
    parser.parse yaml, filename
    parser.handler.root
  end
end
```

Comment: Check your YAML config files, you probably have a typo in one of them.

Comment: will do, but it seems odd that I would have a typo in a file that has been just installed. If I do they are still having problems with the psych gem like before.

Comment: That last comment got butchered by the lack of formatting in comments, you might have better luck adding it to the question. You could try switching YAML parsers in `config/boot.rb` (`require 'yaml'; YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'` should do the trick).

Comment: New to RoR. Where do I find the config/boot.rb ?

Comment: I am assuming directly within the new application in which I have the problem, but this will mean having to do this for every new application created? I am not sure whats going on. Again, I am new to RoR and I just installed everything using .rvm

Comment: Post the content of the `database.yml` file and the full error trace.

Comment: In your rails app there's a 'config' folder and within that folder you should find the file 'boot.rb' :)

Comment: you can see the answer in this url: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189128/cant-start-vagrant-after-laravel-homestead-installation-vagrant-up#_=_)

Answer (score 3):

This error usually appears if you have a syntax error in your YAML file(s).

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when I had a tab instead of whitespace in the yaml file.

Comment: Yes me too! Usually I work with tabs in editors than with whitespaces. Correcting the tabs, the instance comes up. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when the YAML ended in a NULL '\0' character instead of empty whitespace.