# Can't start vagrant after Laravel Homestead installation (vagrant up)

Tags: php, laravel

I followed all the steps in the laravel homestead installation, but after issuing 'vagrant up' command I get this messages:

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>
): found a tab character that violate intendation while scanning a plain scalar
at line 17 column 11 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse
_stream'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse
'
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 67):

Ok, I got it... Vagrant is not fond of tabs in the Homestead.yaml file... The indentation must be with spaces and exact.

Just substituted the tabs with spaces and vagrant is able to start.

Comment: Oh, was missing a space XD